# How to replace the diagonal elements of a numpy 2d array with another array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy 2d array:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]])
print (A)
```

I would like to replace the diagonal elements with `a = np.array([0,2,15,20])`. That is the desired output should be:

```
A=[[0, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 2, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 15, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 20]]
```

I tried with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]])
a = np.array([0,2,15,20])
print(np.fill_diagonal(A, a))
```

But it resulted in `None`

Comment: The `np.fill_diagonal` function modifies the input array in-place, it does not return a value. Try `print(A)` afterwards to see result.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method if `a` be the main array and `b` the modified values array:

```
a_mod = a.ravel()
a_mod[::a.shape[0]+1] = b
result = a_mod.reshape(a.shape)
```

It can handle where the other diagonals of a matrix (instead the main diagonal) is of interest, by some modification. [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) works on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
A[np.arange(4), np.arange(4)] = a

array([[ 0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  2,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 15, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 20]])
```